# Powershell-search for users whos account expires with the office information

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can anyone tell me how to use powershell to retrieve AD infor about users whos account expires with the info from the Office field.

Like this Name, Office, Expiredate

And how to send it from the useraccount logged in on the server.

BTW: QADuser is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach ($user in (gwmi -namespace "root/directory/ldap" -class "ds_user"))
{
    write " `
        $user.DS_name, `
        $user.DS_physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
        (w32tm /ntte $user.DS_accountExpires) `
        " `
    | Out-File ".\userlist.txt" -Append -Encoding ASCII;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just using ADSI (works in PowerShell 1 without any snapin)

```
Clear-Host
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","jpb@dom.fr","PWD")

$dsLookFor = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$dsLookFor.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=jblanc)"; 
$dsLookFor.SearchScope = "subtree"; 
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); 
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedame");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("accountexpires");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");

$lstUsr = $dsLookFor.findall()
foreach ($usrTmp in $lstUsr) 
{
  Write-Host $usrTmp.Properties["samaccountname"]
  Write-Host $usrTmp.Properties["name"]
  #Write-Host $usrTmp.Properties["accountexpires"].value
  Write-Host $([datetime]::FromFileTime($($usrTmp.Properties["accountexpires"])))
  Write-Host $usrTmp.Properties["department"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "365" -UsersOnly | Get-ADUser -Prop  
   Description,samAccountName,AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object  
   Name,samAccountName,Description,AccountExpirationDate | Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate |
   Format-Table -property * -AutoSize | Out-file "FilePath\name.txt" -Width 500
```