# how to provide server/OU/DC details to [adsisearcher]?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
$ADResult = ([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$sams)").Findone()
```

I am using this statement to search in the AD the accounts with the samaccountnames as $sams, but the problem is that Im calling this from a different server and not from the one where AD's exist.

So, what I need to know is can I provide it details of the following -

1. Server
2. DC
3. OU

and if yes, HOW?

Comment: You'll find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530207/608772) a full `DirectorySearcher` example.

Answer (score 4):

Set variables for your Domain Controller, Domain, Suffix and OU like this:

```
$DC = "DCServer"
$Domain = "MyDomain"
$Sufix = "Local"
$OU = "MyOU"
$SAMName = "SamAccountName"
```

Link your Searcher object to that info...

```
$Root = [adsi] "LDAP://$DC/OU=$OU,DC=$Domain,DC=$Suffix"
$Searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
$Searcher.filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName= $SAMName))"
$Searcher.FindOne()
```

If you have Sub-OU's Add OU="OU1",OU="OU2" etc.

Comment: and what about the .Findone()    ,plssee the statement i posted

Comment: $Searcher.FindOne() goes in the end, i think i't was trivial sorry, if you cant find anything it's maybe because the OU,  try to run it only with "LDAP://$DC" where $DC is your DC name

Comment: still not doing what i want, I think [adsi] is not doing work for [adsisearcher]

Comment: @MartinWood it sure works,  does $root itself shows any data?

Comment: distinguishedName : {DC=xy,DC=ef}
Path              : LDAP://abc.xy.ef